# Unable to use or install the wacom bamboo tablet

Tags: 11.10, wacom

i am trying to install wacom driver in ubuntu 11.10. I am unable to install it as the driver is only available for gnome 2.:(

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure I saw an icon for Wacom tablets in System Settings using the Gnome 3 interface.

If you have no joy, let me know and I'll try it this evening as I have a Bamboo myself.

Normally, they just work no fiddling around required, although at present mine is connected to a Kubuntu 11.10 PC, my other PC runs Ubuntu 11.10.

**Update**

Okay, just checked Ubuntu 11.10, plugged in my Wacom Bamboo Fun tablet Model CTE-650, just worked!

System Settings contains the settings for the tablet, no drivers required

[image: System Settings]

You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I have already checked that out.